# Why my code is throwing `The semaphore has been disposed` exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, task

In my code I am using `SemaphoreSlim` and after execution of whole `for` loop I am receiving from `App.g.cs` exception `The semaphore has been disposed`, and I can not find out why, if it is disposed only by `using` statement. Here is the code of entire method which usus:

```
public async Task TestHistoricalResultsAsync()
{
    //init values and controls
    CommandStartedControlsSetup("TestResultsCommand");

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    int degreeOfParallelism = 10;
    int loopCounter = 0;
    ProgressBarTick("Testing on historic data", loopCounter, Races.Count, 0);
    using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism))
    {
        //for all races in the file
        for (int i = 0; i < Races.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = i;

            if (TaskCancellation == true)
            {
                break;
            }

            await throttler.WaitAsync(TokenSource.Token);

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => //async
            {
                try
                {
                    CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    //if the race is from 2018
                    if (Races[j].RaceDate.Year == 2018)
                    {
                        Category = Races[j].RaceCategory;
                        Distance = Races[j].RaceDistance.ToString();

                        //for all horses in the race
                        for (int h = 0; h < Races[j].HorseList.Count; h++)
                        {
                            if (TaskCancellation == true)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            HorseDataWrapper horse = new HorseDataWrapper();
                            horse = ParseHorseData(Races[j].HorseList[h], Races[j].RaceDate);
                            Races[j].HorseList[h] = horse; //get all indexes
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //
                }
                finally
                {
                    loopCounter++;

                    ProgressBarTick("Testing on historic data", loopCounter, Races.Count, 0);

                    throttler.Release();
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    try
    {
        //ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        await _dataServices.SaveRaceTestResultsAsync(Races.ToList()); //save the analysis to the file

        AllControlsEnabled = true;

        CommandCompletedControlsSetup();

        VisibilityCancellingMsg = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `throttler` goes out of scope of your using statement before the tasks are executed. The whole point is the tasks are async, so why are you using a `using` block which would only work if they were synchronous?

If you really want to, you'd need to keep the `Task.WhenAll` call inside the `using` block to prevent it from getting disposed.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I based on this example https://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp#to-process-the-maximum-given-number-of-items-in-the-collection-a , you suggest to get rid of `using`, and dispose manually? Or `Release` is disposing it?

Comment: Well, you can't dispose of the semaphore before all your tasks are executed. So either you need to wait for them all to complete inside the `using` block, or manually dispose. Either choice depends how you want to structure your code. And note how in the example, `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` is called _inside_ the `using` block.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I doble checked my code, `throttler` stays within `using`. Do you suggest to get rid of `using`?

Comment: bakunet: You're misunderstanding how scopes work in C#. Basically the scope of the using statement completes because nothing is executed inside it, you're just appending blocks to an array. Afterwards the semaphore is disposed, and first _then_ you're executing the tasks (with a disposed semaphore). I think you should just do manual disposing for now, it'll be easier for you to understand how scopes work that way. (essentially dispose it in the last finally block of your sample code)

Comment: `Task.Run` says (basically) 'do this later'. And `later` is **after** the `Dispose` that `using` causes occurs.

Comment: @mjwills Ill try with async lambda: `tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>`, maybe it fixes problem?

Comment: Ok, I removed `using` statement and placed `throttler.Dispose();` in last `finally` block. And it worked! You are guys awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comment discussion, the issue is that your semaphore goes out of scope. You have two options:

a) Await on the excution of all the tasks inside the block

```
using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism))
{
    // setup the tasks

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    // ...
}
```

b) Manually dispose once the execution of all the task finishes

```
var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism)
{
    // setup the tasks. You can still use a scope block (brackets) here if you want.
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // ...
}
finally 
{
    throttler?.Dispose()
}
```

The second option is most likely going to be more appropriate, but it depends on the final layout of your code.

Comment: The second option is dangerous, since if an exception occurs **before** the `try` then the `Dispose` won't occur.